Determine the Galois group of a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}(x, y)$
Let $K = \mathbb{C}(x, y)=\mathrm{Frac}\left(\mathbb{C}[x, y]\right)$ be the field of rational functions with variables $x$ and $y$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Then
$$
f(R) = x \left( (1+R)^n - 1 \right) - y R (1+R)^n \in K[R]
$$
is a polynomial over $K$, derived from an equation related to interest rate $R$ (we can assume $n\ge 5$). Assume $L$ is a splitting field of $f$, and $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is the Galois group of the field extension $L/K$.
My questions is: how to determine the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$?
I know the Galois group of the following general polynomial
$$
g(R)=R^n+x_1R^{n-1}+x_2R^{n-2}+\cdots +x_n\in F(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)[R]
$$
is the symmetric group $S_n$. Therefore, if $n \geq 5$, the Galois group of $g(R)$ is not solvable. Also for any specific polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$, various techniques such as mod $p$ reduction can be applied, and software like Sage or Magma can be used to compute the Galois group.
However, I have noticed that there is relatively little discussion about the Galois groups of "less general" polynomials, where certain coefficients satisfy specific algebraic relations. I am curious about the techniques that can be used to tackle such problems.
By making the substitution $T=R+1$, the problem reduces to studying the Galois group of
$$
\begin{align*}
h(T)&=-f(T-1)/(T-1)\\
&=\frac{yT^{n+1}-(x+y)T^n+x}{T-1}\\
&=yT^{n}-xT^{n-1}-xT^{n-2}-\cdots-xT-x \in K[T].
\end{align*}
$$
By Eisenstein's criterion, $h(T)$ is irreducible over $K$. So Galois group acts on the set of roots of $h(T)$ transitively. At this point, I am unsure how to proceed. Any assistance with any specific cases (e.g.,
$n=5$) would be greatly appreciated!

Please recall that pure problem statement questions are not well received on this site.

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you for your kind reminder! Could you elaborate on what content would be beneficial for me to add to the question description? I understand that "Missing context or other details" refers to "including background and motivation, relevant definitions, sources, possible strategies, current progress". I have spent time improving it, but still not entirely sure which content is necessary and which is recommended to ensure my question will be accepted. Therefore, I hesitate to include all kinds of related information, as I don’t want to obscure the main point of my question.

The edit has made it much better. Thank you.

Substitute some specific values for x and y and compute the Galois group for the resulting polynomial over Q. If you hit S_n for any choice of x and y, you're done (my guess is that this is by far the most likely scenario), if not, then it's more tricky. You'd then have to establish the existence of some additional relation(s) between the roots of the polynomial other than the ones given by the elementary symmetric functions.

The Galois group of $h(T)$ over $K$ equals the one of $h_n(T)$ $:=$ $T^{n}-xT^{n-1}-xT^{n-2}-\cdots-xT-x$. Take $\boldsymbol{n=5}$ and let $G$ denote the Galois group of $h_5$ over $K_0$ $:=$ $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. We will show $G$ $=$ $S_5$. (This does not mean the group is necessarily the same over $K$. For instance, $T^5-x$ has a group of order 20 over $K_0$, while it has group $C_5$ over $K$.)
The following theorem is often useful. Let $A$ be a domain, $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal with quotient ring $\overline{A}=A/\mathfrak{p}$, and $f\in A[T]$ such that both $f$ and its reduction $\overline{f}\in\overline{A}[T]$ are separable (but not necessarily irreducible). Then the Galois group of
$\overline{f}$ over $\mathrm{Frac}(\overline{A})$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the group of $f$ over $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$. For the proof, see van der Waerden, Algebra I, §66, second theorem. [Edit: $f$ must be monic.]
Taking $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(x+11)$, this yields that $G$ contains the Galois group $H$ of the polynomial $l(T)$ $:=$ $T^5+11T^4+11T^3+11T^2+11T+11$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subgroup. Thus it suffices to show $H$ $=$ $S_5$. Since $l(T)$ is irreducible (Eisenstein), $H$ is transitive. Use the theorem again, now with $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(3)$. As $l(T)$ $\equiv$ $(T^2+T-1)(T^3+T^2-T+1)$ mod $3$, with both factors irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[T]$, we find $H$ $\subseteq$ $S_5$ contains a permutation conjugate to $(12)(345)$, hence it contains a 2-cycle. And mod $7$, $l(T)$ is the product of $T-1$ and the irreducible $T^4-2T^3+2T^2-T+3$. So $H$ contains a 4-cycle. But, for all $n$, the only transitive subgroup $H$ $\subseteq$ $S_n$ containing a 2-cycle and an ($n-1$)-cycle is $S_n$ itself. (Van der Waerden, loc. cit., third theorem.)

Very good answer. A small suggestion though: instead of framing this answer as a "repeated application" the (first-mentiond) theorem from van der Waerden, it would be more cleanly stated as a single application for the prime ideals $(3,x+11)$ and $(7,x+11)$ of $A$. However, your approach may be better for didactic purposes.
